# EF Core async select InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The following code

```
var merchant = await _dbContext.Merchants
   .Include(m => m.Users)
   .SingleAsync(m => m.MerchantId == id);
 
var userTasks = merchant.Users.Select(async u =>
{
   var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u);

   return new MerchantUser
   {
      UserName = u.UserName,
      Role = string.Join(",", roles)
   };
}).ToList();

var users = await Task.WhenAll(userTasks);
            
return View(new MerchantViewModel
{
   MerchantId = merchant.MerchantId,
   MerchantName = merchant.Name,
   MerchantUsers = users.ToList()
});
```

sometimes returns this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.

However, this code does not. To my understanding, it's doing the same thing so I don't understand why it's failing.

```
var merchant = await _dbContext.Merchants
    .Include(m => m.Users)
    .SingleAsync(m => m.MerchantId == id);

var users = new List<MerchantUser>();
            
foreach (var user in merchant.Users)
{
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                
    users.Add(new MerchantUser
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Role = string.Join(",", roles)
    });
}
            
return View(new MerchantViewModel
{
    MerchantId = merchant.MerchantId,
    MerchantName = merchant.Name,
    MerchantUsers = users
});
```

Comment: one same `DbContext` cannot perform 2 asynchronous queries, if you need to query more than one query concurrently, you need more than one DbContexts (or connections if executing query directly).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
var userTasks = merchant.Users.Select(async u => { … }).ToList();
var users = await Task.WhenAll(userTasks);
```

This will *asynchronously* start all those `Select` tasks *at the same time* and then wait for them to complete. So this will run multiple things in parallel. Since you are querying the user manager inside, this will not work since the underlying connection does not support parallel queries.

In contrast, your `foreach` loop will only run *one* query at a time, awaiting the `GetRolesAsync` before the next iteration begins. So instead of working in parallel, the roles will be read *sequentially* for all users.

Comment: I find it weird that EF accepts async lambda functions as LINQ predicates/functions. Can this be caught at runtime ? AFAIK, this will **always** fail right ?

Comment: This is nothing about EF though, `merchant.Users` is a in-memory list of the previously loaded users from your first query. And then you run LINQ’s `Select` on it which will just apply a function on each element. It’s just in your special case that you are running a database operation inside of each of those functions and run everything in parallel with `Task.WhenAll`. – But yes, this situation will likely always fail. It’s a bad idea to use `Task.WhenAll` with a (lazy) enumerable of tasks that trigger database operations.